# Getting Ink Strokes in MyScript

Tags: image-processing, web

I'm working with MyScript, and I noticed that for the web API (find examples here: http://doc.myscript.com/MyScriptCloud/3.1.0/myscript-cloud/examples.html), a "stroke" type is required, as well as all of the coordinates describing the stroke.

I'm wondering what software I should use to generate these strokes, or how I could program it myself? There's nothing in the official documentation.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The stroke type expected by the server is a json object with x, y attributes, containing both arrays of integer. These values represent x,y coordinates user input while writing on the device touchscreen. You can collect and add timestamp as an optional ‘t’ attribut of the JSON stroke type structure.

As a first option, you can use our webcomponents : myscript-math-web, myscript-text-web or even MyScriptJS to manage the user ink capture and the rendering in a canvas.

You can also grab the user handwriting by yourself, in this case we recommend you to use (jquery PEP)[https://github.com/jquery/PEP] (Pointer Event Polyfill) that will help you to manage user touchscreen events, namely pointer events.

You will have to listen for pointerdown, pointermove and pointerup events. Once such event occurs, add the event coordinates to your structure this way, for instance:

var myStroke;
document.querySelector('#myCanvasId').addEventListener('pointerdown', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                mystroke = {x : [], y : [], t : []};
                mystroke.x.push(e.clientX);
                mystroke.y.push(e.clientY);
                        mystroke.t.push(e.timestamp)
        }, false);

document.querySelector('#myCanvasId').addEventListener('pointermove', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                mystroke.x.push(e.clientX);
                mystroke.y.push(e.clientY);
                        mystroke.t.push(e.timestamp)
        }, false);

document.querySelector('#myCanvasId').addEventListener('pointerup', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                mystroke.x.push(e.clientX);
                mystroke.y.push(e.clientY);
                        mystroke.t.push(e.timestamp)

```
                    // Send your stroke to the server
                    mystroke = {};
    }, false);
```

If you need more detailed explanation, you can have a look at [this video](https://dev.myscript.com/myscript-cdk-part-1-develop-your-first-cdk-application/). Details about digital ink capture at 10:40.